# Remove one-character words

Tags: regex, bash, perl, awk, sed

I'm looking for a regexp to remove one character words. I don't mind whether using `perl`, `awk`, `sed` or `bash` built-ins.

Test case:

```
$ echo "a b c d e f g h ijkl m n opqrst u v" | $COMMAND
```

Desired output:

```
ijkl opqrst
```

What I've tried so far:

```
$ echo "a b c d e f g h ijkl m n opqrst u v" | sed 's/ . //g'
acegijkln opqrstv
```

I'm guessing that:

- the `a` isn't removed because there is no white space before it
- the `c` remains because once the `b` has been removed, there is no more whitespace before it
- and so on...

Attempt #2:

```
$ echo "a b c d e f g h ijkl m n opqrst u v" | sed 's/\w.\w//g'
     s v
```

Here I don't get at all what's happening.

Any help + explanations are welcome, I want to learn.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Learning Regular Expressions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4736/learning-regular-expressions)

Comment: Hum I disagree, there is a specific question in my post.

Comment: `.` matches *any* character, including space. `\w` matches word characters, so I don't see what you're attempting with `\w.\w`.

Comment: ‘*there is a specific question in my post*’ Would you mind pointing it out? I can't find it.

Comment: As the post title states, I'm trying to remove one-character words. I thought that `.` didn't match whitespace, that's a good start, thanks.

Comment: @nicoco, You can try with word boundary (`\b`).

Comment: @nicoco That's not a *question*, though. IMHO, this looks like a give-me-the-code post.

Comment: @sat Thanks, I didn't know this one.

Comment: @Biffen: I disagree. The OP has written a solution to their problem and is asking for help to get it working.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have to use word boundary `\b` (or) `\<` and `\>` respectively match the empty string at the beginning and end of a word.

```
echo "a b c d e f g h ijkl m n opqrst u v" | sed 's/\b\w\b \?//g'
```

(OR)

```
echo "a b c d e f g h ijkl m n opqrst u v" | sed 's/\<.\> \?//g'
```

Comment: It leaves a lot of white spaces before the "long" words, but I can work with that. Thanks!

Comment: @nicoco You can use `s/\b\w\b ?//g` to remove the whispaces aswell.

Comment: Be very careful with `\b`: what you have will clobber things like "will-o'-the-wisp" and "Build-A-Bear".

Comment: Or the same solution with GNU awk: `awk '{gsub(/\<.\> ?/,"")}1'`.

Answer (score 4):

You could simply use `grep`:

```
echo "a b c d e f g h ijkl m n opqrst u v"  | grep -o '[a-z]\{2,\}'
```

where the regex is matching any word composed with at least 2 characters.

The `-o` option in `grep` prints the matching pattern (and not the entire line).

Comment: You could use `grep -E` so you wouldn't need those pesky backslashes.

Comment: It should be noted that this separates all matches with a newline, which is not exactly the same as the desired output as written in the question.  This may or may not be a problem, depending on the circumstances.

Comment: In that case, pipe into `| paste -sd " "`

Answer (score 2):

Albeit, `Awk` is not the most efficient of ways to do this, answering only because it is tagged [awk](/questions/tagged/awk), using its `length()` string function. It is `POSIX` compliant, so no issues on portability.

```
echo "a b c d e f g h ijkl m n opqrst u v" | \
  awk '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) {if (length($i)>1) { printf "%s ", $i }} }'
ijkl opqrst
```

Comment: You shouldn't say `awk is not the most efficient way....`, just that the specific awk code you posted is not the most efficient way.

Comment: @EdMorton: As you say Ed! May be you can correct my logic or provide a more efficient way for this.

Comment: I added the awk equivalent of the accepted answer under that answer, see http://stackoverflow.com/a/41693834/1745001

Comment: @EdMorton: Well! everybody can't answer in the same _class_ as of Ed Morton in `awk`

Answer (score 1):

Perl solution: just filter elements on [`length`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/length.html)

```
echo "a b c d e f g h ijkl m n opqrst u v" | perl -lanE \
  'say join " ", grep {length($_) > 1} @F'
```

Comment: If you want to be more terse, you can omit the default variable: `grep {length > 1} @F`

Answer (score 1):

Just for fun, another option: translate spaces to newlines and look for lines with at least 2 characters

```
$ echo "a b c d e f g h ijkl m n opqrst u v" | tr ' ' '\n' | grep .. | paste -sd " "
ijkl opqrst
```

Answer (score 0):

Not being familiar with any linux sprung tools, this is somewhat of a guess, but I think the (a) regex you want is

```
(?:\s\w\b|\b\w\s)
```

like

```
$ echo "a b c d e f g h ijkl m n opqrst u v" | sed 's/(?:\s\w\b|\b\w\s)//g'
```

This would replace any single character either preceded by, or foolowed by, a space with nothing.

[Check the regex out here at regex101](https://regex101.com/r/UQePV3/1).

Comment: sed -r 's/(\s\w\b|\b\w\s)//g'

Answer (score 0):

Another in awk. A non-space (`[^ ]`) is considered a word. Feel free to replace it with your definition of a word.

```
$ awk '{while(sub(/^[^ ] | [^ ]$/,"")||sub(/ [^ ] /," "));}1'
```

Using `sub` it replaces `[a space][non-space][a space]` tuples with a space
and removes from the beginning and end of record the single characters and leading / trailing space. It's in a `while` so it keeps doing it until there are no hits left. To test it:

```
$ echo "a b c d e f g h ijkl m n opqrst u v"|awk '{while(sub(/^[^ ] | [^ ]$/,"")||sub(/ [^ ] /," "));}1'
ijkl opqrst
```

Answer (score -1):

```
echo "a b c d e f g h ijkl m n opqrst u v"  | grep -wo "\b[a-z][a-z]\+\b"
```

Comment: With `-w` you don't need the `\b` anchors.